# Bazaar hook to check commit message on server

Tags: bazaar, pre-commit-hook

We have a bazaar server, to which many people connect. I'd like to run some pre-commit hooks for every user and to me it'd make most sense to run these hooks on the server, since I can't control all computers connecting. I was assuming this was a simple task but I'm stuck now.

My current status is:

- If I install the script on my workstation will the hook work.
- If I install the script on the server will it work for commits done there.
- With it installed on the server and I commit on my workstation it's
  being loaded but ignored.

I've tried having the script in both `BZR_PLUGIN_PATH` and `~/.bazaar/plugin` on the server, and if I do that I see this in the log:

```
0.112  looking for plugins in /home/me/.bazaar/plugins
0.122  looking for plugins in /usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/bzrlib/plugins
0.123  Plugin name my_test_hook already loaded
```

And that's from a remote workstation so the plugin obviously gets loaded, but not executed. I've dumbed it down so what it's curretly doing is:

```
def my_test_hook (local, master, old_revno, old_revid,
    future_revno, future_revid, tree_delta, future_tree):
    raise TipChangeRejected("Rejected")
```

So it's kind of obvious when it's being executed. Can someone please tell me what I need to do to get this working? Ie when I do `"bzr ci -m '...'"` on my workstation do I want the hook in my server to cancel the commit and say "Rejected".

The documentation hasn't really helped me much unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: You can't.

The remote host only sees a post-push and then it's too late to stop the commit so such a hook has to run locally on every client.